# How to update the value of an existing row instead of adding new row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

what i want first of all how do i detect if item is already exist. if item already exist in Datagrid row then on inserting new row update that specific item instead of adding new row

```
public class ProductModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public int Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Product_Quantity { get; set; }
    .....
```

Observeable Collection

```
    private ObservableCollection<ProductModel> mProducts { get; set; } = null;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> Products
    {
        get
        {
            mProducts = mProducts ?? new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
            return mProducts;
        }
    }
```

Binding To Datagrid

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
```

this is how add items to collection

```
 Products.Add(new ProductModel{ Product_ID = 1, Product_Name = "Product Name 1", Product_Quantity = 1 });
 Products.Add(new ProductModel{ Product_ID = 2, Product_Name = "Product Name 2", Product_Quantity = 5 });
 Products.Add(new ProductModel{ Product_ID = 3, Product_Name = "Product Name 3", Product_Quantity = 2 });
```

below where my logic should go. if item exsits then update existed row else add new row

```
private ICommand mAddItemCommand;
    public ICommand AddItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mAddItemCommand== null)
            {
                mAddItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
                {
                    Products.Add(new ProductModel{ Product_ID = 2, Product_Name = "Product Name 2", Product_Quantity = 1 });
                });
            }
            return mAddItemCommand;
        }
    }
```

On clicking above command where the Product_ID was 2 Product_Quantity should become 6 which 5 before.

Sorry for bad explanation..
thanks in advance

Comment: Then you need to put that logic in the delagate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that would perform the desired functionality

```
public void AddProduct(ProductModel product) {
    var item = Products.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Product_ID == product.Product_ID);
    if(item != null) {
        item.Product_Quantity += product.Product_Quantity;
    } else {
        Products.Add(product);
    }
}
```

and call it within the delegate with the item to be added or updated.

```
//...
delegate () {
    ProductModel product = //However you intend on getting the item
    AddProduct(product);
}
//...
```

Comment: thanks, this is the perfect answer, i may need more help